# How can I play video in full screen without changing the video aspect ratio in Air

Tags: video, air, flex4, fullscreen, aspect-ratio

I am creating an applciation in Air using SDK 4.1 which plays videos. For doing this I created a UIComponent and added Video object in UIComponent. Video file is .flv format.

Now when I make video full screen then video aspect ratio is changed. The video is stretching. 
I am giving video dimensions by using the code below:

```
myVideo = new Video( 766 , 572 );
```

So please guide me, how can I make video fullscreen without changing the video aspect ratio.

Any web link or source code would be appreciated for implementing the solution.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved this problem by creating a parent component that contains the video component.  I set the parent component to the full size of the application and then I size the video to fit those bounds instead of using the formal fullscreen feature.  It gives the same effect of fullscreen without messing with aspect ratio.